# How to install Grub on PC with Ubuntu 13.10_x64 from live DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, dvd

Preface:
This is my first Ubuntu install from a live DVD. I have very little experience with GNU/Linux; however I have in the past installed Kwheezy after burning an ISO without any problems.

Regarding install failure of Grub from Ubuntu 13.10 Live DVD this is the error message
that I receive:

Unable to Intall Grub in /dev/sda

Executing ' grub-install/dev/dag' failed.

This is a fatal error.
S
I am trying this installation on a desktop PC with 16g of ram and 3+tb of hds.
And is AMD64 powered.
Please any assistance will be greatly appreciated. And quiet my Son's criticism
that Linux starts out and usually stays "broken", and is not for the most part
for non PC power users. In advance, thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to this? [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056789](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056789&p=12234431#post12234431)

Possible causes:

- The install completed correctly but GRUB failed for whatever reason. In this case, run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This can be done straight from the LiveDVD.
- The wrong architecture was selected. Sometimes if you try installing a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit system (and vise versa) strange things can happen. Verify that you selected the correct OS version for your hardware.
- Attempt reinstall? - Occasionally something can go wrong during install that can't be explained. Sometimes this can be fixed with a reinstall, but that is not guaranteed. I would attempt a repair before a full reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have tried your suggestions multiple times before posting. I problem could be that my desktop is a high-powered custom built gifted to me by my son. Actually that is what he considers to be problem and that is what he has been trying to suss out. In the meantime we might install Fedora 20 so I can continue study of the GNU/Linux command-line. My real goal is to install Ubuntu 14.04 coming out on the 17th of April and throughly learn the FOSS environment and then help teach others locally about Free and Open Source Software. Again, thanks for your suggestions.